# How to verify that Slick is using parameters from application.conf?

Tags: database, scala, slick, hikaricp

In application.conf, parameters are set:

```
  url = "jdbc:mysql://.../table_name"
  user = ...
  password = ...
  driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
  connectionPool = HikariCP
  queueSize = 25000
```

I am still receiving an error whenever the queue reaches 1000 items, meaning that the queueSize property is still the default value.

```
Task scala.slick.backend.DatabaseComponent$DatabaseDef$... 
rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor...
[Running, pool size = 20, 
active threads = 20, 
queued tasks = 1000, 
completed tasks = 7507]
```

Comment: Here's a simple example of how to read values from Typesafe config - https://github.com/kevinmeredith/typesafe_config_read_env_var.

Comment: Thank you, your test helped! I used Database.forConfig("", ConfigFactory.load().getConfig("")) and it allowed the queueSize variable to be found.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it's not picking up your value, but you might want to try a different way of configuring.. you didn't say what version of Slick you are using. But please refer to the [Slick 3.0.0 documentation](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0/database.html). Try it using [TypeSafe Config](https://github.com/typesafehub/config):

In your `application.conf`:

```
database {
  dataSourceClass = "org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource" // replace with mysql driver
  properties = {
    databaseName = "mydb"
    user = "myuser"
    password = "secret"
  }
  queueSize = 25000 // I've never changed that property, so not tested.
}
```

Then in scala:

```
val db = Database.forConfig("database")
```

Hope this works for you.